# #396 Importing CSV and Excel Couldn't find Employee without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, csv

I'm working with rails 4. I follow Railscast tutorial and get the file selected, but when I import I get this error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /employees/import
Couldn't find Employee without an ID

Gem roo

routes file

```
 resources :employees do
      collection { post :import }
      end
```

Model

```
    class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.import(file)
   allowed_attributes = ["identifier","first_name","last_name","address","phone"]
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    employee = Employee.where(id: employee_hash["id"]) || new
    employee.attributes = row.to_hash.select { |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }
    employee.save!

  if employee.count == 1
        employee.first.update_attributes(employee_hash)
      else
        Employee.create!(employee_hash)
      end # end if !product.nil?

  end # end self.import(file)
end # end class

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end

end

end
```

Employee Controller

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_employee, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :import]

  # GET /employees
  # GET /employees.json
  def index
  @employee = Employee.where(:status => true)
  @turnover_employee = Employee.where(:status => false)
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @employee.to_csv}
    format.xls #{ send_data @employee.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") } /// Alternativa ///

   end
  end


  def import
  Product.import(params[:file,:id])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Products imported."
end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_employee
      @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def employee_params
      params.require(:employee).permit(:identifier, :first_name, :last_name, :address, :phone, :status, :service_company_id)
    end
end
```

Index Form for import

```
<%= form_tag import_employees_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file, :class=> "btn  icon-upload"  %> |
  <%= submit_tag "Importar", :class=> "btn  icon-upload" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using this code:

```
def self.import(file)
  allowed_attributes = ["identifier","first_name","last_name","address","phone"]
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    employee = find_by_identifier(row["identifier"]) || new
    employee.attributes = row.to_hash.select { |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }
    employee.save!
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end

end
```

- I change the id to search for identifier. because in excel the
  employee had no id, but identifier. and delete the employee count that
  didn't help.
- An other change was '
  from:

  ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)

to:

```
".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, :ignore)
```

- Delete the require 'iconv' works for rails 4
  [Link that help me](http://sunilsharma3639.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/importing-csv-and-excel-in-rails-4-and-ruby-2-0/)

Comment: It would make your answer better if you would explain what you did and not only post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your model's import class method:

```
employee = Employee.where(id: employee_hash["id"]) || new
```

is not finding a value in `employee_hash["id"]`.  So you are effectively doing `Employee.where(id: nil)`

I can't see anywhere where employee_hash is getting set to anything.

Comment: Got it working for csv ill post a update on the code and see if I can get some help on that code. thankx for reply so fast